# Vue Router, construct a route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am making a data table with a search field in my application and I would like to implement the following behaviour:

> When a user types a research, the URL gets updated. If a user clicks
>   on a link and hit "back" from his navigator, he gets back to his last
>   search.

For the moment, I am doing the following thing:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search (value) {
      this.$router.replace('/products?search=' + value)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using the `replace` function of the router. That allows me to make it work. And it's better than the `push` method because if a user hits "back" during a search, he will go to his last page and not last research, and that's exactly what I want.

However, I don't like how I hard write the URL.

I would love to make something like that:

```
watch: {
  search (value) {
    let route = new Route(this.$route)

    route.query.search = value

    this.$router.replace(route.getPath())
  }
}
```

Because, let's imagine that the user has other parameters like pagination or something like that, they would be erased. I would like a method that takes my actual url and add/replace a query string parameter.

Is this something I can achieve with Vue Router or do I need to do something else: Other package / Vanilla JS?

Comment: Have you considered nested routes and `/products/search/something` path? Might be a better approach (or not :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the object location parameter `$router.replace`? Eg:

```
watch: {
  search (value) {
    this.$router.replace({ path: 'products', query: { search: value }})
  }
}
```